# From PhpStorm to VSCode. Is there 'best practice suggestion' like in PhpStorm

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, phpstorm

When I was using PhpStorm I got best practice suggestions with yellow underline and a light bulb to for example use const instead of define. Example:

```php
define("MENU_MAIN", "main-menu");
define("MENU_MOBILE", "mobile-menu");
define("MENU_FOOTER_1", "footer1");
```

Now I am using VSCode and can't find any similar functionality. Is there any extension or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be extensions that can highlight sections like this for code quality (I could not find any popular ones doing a quick search). However, there is not anything native in VSCode that does what you are looking for.

I'd suggest looking into a tool like [PHP_CodeSniffer](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer) which doesn't care what IDE you use.

Comment: Yes, that was phpcs what I have been looking for.